# Python3, listen a specific channel of mic array

Tags: python-3.x, channel, microphone, pyaudio

I'm trying to listen the first (0) channel of a mic array (Respeaker v2.0) with Python 3.7.

At this time, I can listen on the 6 channels :

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(
            rate=16000,
            format=p.get_format_from_width(2),
            channels=6,
            input=True,
            input_device_index=5)
```

But when I want to record in a buffer :

```
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK_SIZE * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
    stream.write(data, CHUNK_SIZE)
```

How to select the channel "0" ?

With the Respeaker V2.0, the channel 0 contains the voice detected (and channel 5 contains the playback output)

I cannot see any option to do that with PyAudio :(

*NB: If I write the stream into a WAV file, and open it with Audacity, I can select the first channel and it effectively contains the voice cleaned*

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RESPEAKER_RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    a0 = np.fromstring(data,dtype=np.int16)[0::6]
    # if you want to get channel 1 data
    # a1 = np.fromstring(data,dtype=np.int16)[1::6]

    a = a0.tostring()

    frames.append(a)
```

the document:
http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker_Mic_Array_v2.0/

Answer (score 0):

this works with two channels both for local files and with a stream of data.

Local file.

```
# audio channel balance local file
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import wave
import time

wf = wave.open('2chan_audio.wav', 'r')
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# two channels
channel_balance = [0.1, 1]

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    data = wf.readframes(frame_count)
    data_as_np = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
    data_as_np = data_as_np.reshape(frame_count, wf.getnchannels())
    data_as_np = np.int16(data_as_np * channel_balance)
    return data_as_np, pyaudio.paContinue

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.01)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
wf.close()
p.terminate()
```

Stream of data.

```
# audio channel balance stream
WIDTH = 2
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

channel_balance = [0.1, 1]

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    data_as_np = np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype=np.int16)
    data_as_np = data_as_np.reshape(frame_count, CHANNELS)
    data_as_np = np.int16(data_as_np * channel_balance)
    return data_as_np, pyaudio.paContinue

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.01)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Whilst this looked interesting, you appear to suggest a method that provides two channels in the output, whereas the questioner is specifically trying to get channel 0 from the ReSpeaker's six channels